# Dropdown Toggle Doesn't Work on Heroku ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am working on using a bootstrap template to help a friend with a landing page. I am having a similar issue as others, but there solutions are not working for me. Everything works properly on my LocalHost, but when I push it to Heroku, the Bootstrap Dropdown toggle does NOT work...

I am a junior developer trying to learn and challenge myself here, so please explain your answer if applicable. Thank S.O

I have also ran these codes after I think I have a solution ...

```
    heroku run rake assets:reset
    heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

This is my Application.js file

```
    //= require bootstrap
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require_tree .

    // Bootstrap core JavaScript
    @import "jquery.min.js";
    @import "bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
    //Plugin JavaScript
    @import "jquery.easing.min.js";
    //Contact form JavaScript 
    @import "jqBootstrapValidation.js";
    @import "contact_me.js";
    //Custom scripts for this template
    @import "js/agency.min.js";
```

Application.scss File.

```
    *
    *= require_self
    */

    @import "bootstrap";
    @import "font-awesome.css";

    @import "bootstrap.min.css";

    @import "agency.min.css";
    @import "agency.css";

    @import "font-awesome.css";
    @import "font-awesome.min.css";
```

Comment: What's is you rails version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this standard format, more explanation see the [Rails Guide Asset Organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization).

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.easing
//= require jqBootstrapValidation
//= require contact_me
//= require js/agency.min
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Without these lines remove all from `application.js` file, look here is `jquery.easing` for this you need to install [jquery.easing gem](https://github.com/rocsci/jquery-easing-rails) and the `jqBootstrapValidation` you need to install [jqBootstrapValidation gem](https://github.com/matthewpbyrne/jqBootstrapValidation) or if you have those original files then just import to the directory like `app/assets/javascripts/jqBootstrapValidation.js` and `application.js` the same which is now.

You don't need

```
@import "jquery.min.js";
@import "bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
```

because these have already in the asset pipeline. It should work.